# tiny scrollbar and slim scrollbar (jQuery plugins) not working on Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins

I wanted to include a scroll bar jQuery plugin in my Rails project, and I tried "Tiny Scrollbar" and "Slim Scrollbar", but none of them worked.

Here is my codes in the view page (for "Tiny Scrollbar"):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
  });
</script>
....
....
....
<div id="scrollbar1">
  <div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
    <div class="viewport">
      <div class="overview">

      <p> contents </p>


      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I included jquey.tinyscrollbar.min.js in app/assets/javascripts folder, and I'm pretty sure some of the codes worked because when my cursor was on "scrollbar1" div, my wheel did not scroll the page any more. However, nothing happened when I was using slim scrollbar.
I am using Rails 3.2. And here are the pages for the two plugins:

http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/

Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: Were you including the respective CSS?

Comment: Oh yes, I just found out that I forgot to add the css file. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that I did not add the respective CSS file. Problem solved now. Thanks!